# Verify this sum $\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\frac{{2j \choose j}{2n \choose j}}{(-2)^j(2j-1)}=-(4n+1)\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to show that

$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\frac{{2j \choose j}{2n \choose j}}{(-2)^j(2j-1)}=-(4n+1)\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$

This double ${2j \choose j}{2n \choose j}$ is given me a difficult to to simplify the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the ideas from answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047567/) apply here.

For a "pencil and paper approach" this time we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{2j}{j}\frac{x^j}{(-2)^j(2j-1)}=-\sqrt{1+2x}\qquad\Big(|x|<\frac12\Big)$$
so the sum is minus the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in (the power series of) $(1+x)^{2n}\sqrt{1+2x}$.

Which, for small $r>0$, is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{(1+z)^{2n}\sqrt{1+2z}}{z^{2n+1}}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|w|=r}\frac{\sqrt{1-w^2}}{(1-w)^2}\frac{dw}{w^{2n+1}}$$
(a substitution $z=w/(1-w)$ is made), i.e. the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ in the expansion of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}/(1-x)^2$; as we're looking for even powers, we may take
$$\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}=\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}=2(1-x^2)^{-3/2}-(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$$
instead. Finally, the sum is
$$-2\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}+\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=-(4n+1)\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$
as expected.